# Android Studio: "Import Module" changes structure of existing library

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, dependency-management, android-gradle-plugin

I want to import an existing 3rd party library project to my own project as a module. I use "New -> Module -> Import Existing Project" wizard of Android Studio 0.6.1, and it does the job BUT makes a lot of modifications in source code of that library (rearranges source folders, modifies build.gradle, etc.).

Is there a way I can import library project as is, with no changes introduced by import plugin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like there is no way to avoid modifications made by the import plugin. All the settings it has is three checkboxes related to dependency management. I tried to uncheck all of them but still it does change my project structure.

I managed to add existing library projects manually:
1) Copied library's directory under the root directory of my project.
2) Referenced that library in `settings.gradle` by adding `include ':libraryA'`.
3) Added dependency to my project's `build.gradle`: `compile project(':libraryA')`.

Moreover, after that the IDE recognized that library as module and highlighted its folder in bold font whithin Project Structure.